# Fatal error: Call to undefined function runQuery()

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have used the below code to create a database just fine before. But now when copy and pasting this same code to build from a different database I get the Fatal error: Call to undefined function runQuery() on line 89.

I'm just confused as I am defining the function the same way in both databases, but for one it doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

```
  // Create connection object to my localhost

         $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mysql", "donsKayakWorld");

        // Check connection

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        // Start with a new database to start primary keys at 1


         $sql = "DROP DATABASE " . DATABASE_NAME;
         runQuery($sql, "DROP " . DATABASE_NAME, true);


        // Create database if it doesn't exist

        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . DATABASE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

runQuery() is some custom function in the other project that makes the proper call to query the database. It's not working in this other project because it does not exist there. That's why you're getting the error that runQuery is undefined- because it cannot be found in that project, or if it does exist somewhere in the project it is not being included.

Procedural:

```
$sql = "DROP DATABASE " . DATABASE_NAME;
    mysqli_query($sql, "DROP " . DATABASE_NAME, true);
```

OOP:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "DATABASE_NAME");

$sql = "DROP DATABASE " . DATABASE_NAME;
    mysqli->query($sql, "DROP " . DATABASE_NAME, true);
```

Edited based on your code update:

```
$sql = "DROP DATABASE " . DATABASE_NAME;
    $conn->query($sql, "DROP " . DATABASE_NAME, true);
```

Comment: That is odd because I am defining the runQuery in the exact same way.

Comment: If this helped with this issue- don't forget to accept this answer. =)